# How to customize a config file as specified by the values of a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, config

I have a configuration file which has some lines commented out with a '#' which looks like this.

```
#year=1889
#model=foo
#size=small
working=y
```

Now I get some variables from another place in the code which are stored in a dictionary. Values that appear in the config should be commented in and, if necessary, adjusted to their value

```
mydict = {
  "model":"bar",       # <- uncommented+adjusted
  "size":"small",      # <- uncommented
  "working":"y",       # <- untouched
  "newValue":"new"     # <- not added
}
```

The file should look something like this, after it was edited:

```
#year=1889
model=bar
size=small
working=y
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are have? It should be straight forward to follow your description, read the config file, apply the rules and saving the updated config. Even regex should not be needed as long as the config follows the structure you presented. Just some splits and joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you could do it by loading your config file line by line, checking if value is present in dict and if so replacing values and uncommenting like that:

```
new_lines =[]
with open(config_path, "r") as file:
  for line in file:
    name = line.split('=')[0].replace('#', '')
    if name in my_dict:
      new_lines.append(f'{name}={my_dict[name]}')
    else:
      new_lines.append(line)
```

Then you could write it to config file:

```
  with open(config_path, "w") as file:
    for line in new_lines:
      file.write(line + "\n")
```

But I think the better way would be just to use your dictionary as a config and in case of missing parameter checking in config file (it should be less messy).

Comment: There seems to be an error with your first append call. It just replaces each line with your string in single braces instead of expanding the variables first. Just a missing 'f' and a different pair of quotes. I guess. But besides that it seems to work

Comment: Yes, you are right it should be and f-string, my bad.